# Why are eback() and pbase() in std::basic_streambuf named differently?

Tags: c++, history

Presumably the names are stuck now for compatibility, but why were they not given similar names originally? `gptr()` / `pptr()` and `egptr()` / `epptr()` are consistent, but `eback()` is particularly confusing, was `gbase()` already used elsewhere?

Comment: I never really paid attention to the distinction until now. It probably has a long boring back story behind it.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but if you look at the parts of the C++ standard that come from the IOStreams library, you will find many such inconsistencies there. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I could find towards a possible answer is the book [Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales: Advanced Programmer's Guide and Reference](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=0201183951). In this book, Angelika Langer talks with the actual creators of the standard iostream library and compiles information about the rationale behind their design decisions regarding implementation, naming, and a litany of other useful and important things.

The preface of the book *does* mention the six pointers to the the get and put areas of streambuf objects. Perhaps he goes into more detail on the names. Either way, it is still a good read.

Comment: I had a flick through the preface but I didn't find any references to the pointer funcs, do you have a page number?

Comment: Sorry, that was [page 87](http://books.google.com/books?id=5qybChHSk7QC&pg=PA87&vq=pointers&output=html_text&source=gbs_search_r&cad=1).